# Sturmey Archer three speed gear cable snapped quick fix?

Tags: gears

I am buying a very old bike with a snapped gear cable on a three speed Sturmey Archer set up. Before I replace the cable etc. I was thinking of riding it around for a while in 2nd gear. Is there a way I can lock off the gears in second easily? It's been a while since I had a go at any bike stuff!

Comment: Unscrew the barrel adjuster in the cable where it connects to the little chain coming out of the hub until it's ALMOST all the way out -- leave maybe 3 turns screwed in.  Then jury-rig some way to anchor the cable to the frame so that it's taut.  (You'll need something more than just tape for this.) Finally, screw in the adjuster until you achieve the right gear.  Of course, if the cable broke right at the adjuster you'll need to jury-rig something else.

Comment: (It might work to pull the chain out to the right point, then insert a paper clip or some such through the chain to hold it out.)

Comment: That's great Daniel, I'll give it a go. Thank you...love using paper clps!